# Javascript: Cutting/Removing excess characters from a string if it exceeds the Limit

Tags: javascript, logic

Say I have a variable whose length is dynamic meaning it is random, I want to change its length to the first 5 or a certain amount of characters regardless of the length of the characters existing in the variable.

Comment: On the title you mention you want to work on a string. On the question you mention you have an integer variable... Can you explain better what you need? It's always useful to put examples as well.

Comment: Example code you have tried? What is the input, what is the output?

Comment: Please provide example data showing the expected input and output.  If the value is '600000' should that be '60000', '00000', or '0' ?

Comment: @Arnau well it's a string of numbers if that makes sense

Comment: @epascarello as i mentioned earlier i have no idea what to type to get to the goal

Comment: @Yogi Well let's say the Math.random() generates a number like '0.251241536626' then I want to shorten it down to '0.251'

Comment: `foo.toFixed(3)`

Comment: Why does the question ask how to trim an integer when it's actually a floating-point value?  That's kind of an important detail - lol.

Comment: @Yogi I don't know man I'm new to this stuff and trying to get my head around it, There! i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code...

```
const str = "the string";
const start = 0;
// const end = str.length;
str.substring(start, (optional) end);
```

So if you want just first five characters, you do something like

```
str.substring(0, 5);
```

Comment: This code would remove the last 5 characters and it would leave the rest of the characters as is, meaning if I have a string of 20 characters your method would result in 15 remaining characters whereas I want to achieve a total of 5 characters.

Comment: No, you are wrong, this code would remove everything after the fifth character. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 0):

If it's **only integers** (numbers) you could simply generate a random whole number between 11111 and 99999 (so it's always 5 digits), like this:

```
let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 11111);
```

Comment: This would work but the code needs to generate in decimal points as well but your code would only generate positive integers.

Comment: @Zippy do you have a delimited amount of decimals? if not, you should remove Math.floor and convert into string and after that substring as in the other answer (and convert back into a Number if needed as Number). If yes, you should change the "11111" and "99999" to the length of integers needed, and use toFixed() to limit the number of decimals.

Comment: @DavidTaubmannn I think you just cracked the code, It works!!!!

Comment: @Zippy maybe you should expose in a new answer which was your final code.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a delimited amount of decimals? if not, you should remove Math.floor and convert into string and after that substring as in the other answer (and convert back into a Number if needed as Number). If yes, you should change the "11111" and "99999" to the length of integers needed, and use toFixed() to limit the number of decimals. –
DavidTaubmann